# Form get detail not found fastapi

Tags: forms, jinja2, fastapi

I am using FastAPI to render a jinja2 template using a simple get request

This is my template

```html
    <!-- list.html !>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Item Details</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        {% for item in items %}
        <p>{{ item }}</p>
        {% endfor%}
    </body>
    </html>
```

```py
    @app.get("/list_items?search_string={search_string}", response_class=HTMLResponse)
    async def list_items(req: Request, search_string: str):
        print(8*'*', list(search_string))
        items = list(search_string)
        return templates.TemplateResponse("list.html", {"request": req, "items": items})
```

My form is as follows:

```py
    @app.get("/")
    async def read_items():
        html_content = """
        <html>
          <head>
            <title></title>
          </head>
          <body>
            <form action="/list_items/" method="get">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search_string">
              <button type="submit">Search</button>
            </form>
          </body>
        </html>
        """
        return HTMLResponse(content=html_content, status_code=200)
```

However, I get a detail not found error.

Answer (score 0):

You should not include the `{search_string}` part in the route path:

```
@app.get("/list_items?search_string={search_string}", response_class=HTMLResponse)
                                    ^^^^
async def list_items(req: Request, search_string: str):^
```

You're already asking for this when including it as a parameter in your controller definition.

Instead, use the actual path you want to register the route for:

```
@app.get("/list_items", response_class=HTMLResponse)
async def list_items(req: Request, search_string: str):
```

.. and use the same path in your form action:

```
<form action="/list_items" method="get">
```

A small side note: since REST endpoints usually represent resources, a standard naming scheme would use just `/items` instead of `/list_items`, since `GET` on `/items` would mean "list the current items available".